# Form orthongonal group of busses from existing bus (instead of busses of the rows, busses of the columns)

Tags: verilog

I have inputs like this coming into a module:

```
   input  wire [31:0]     row0_Q,
   input  wire [31:0]     row1_Q,
    ...
   input  wire [31:0]     row30_Q,
   input  wire [31:0]     row31_Q
```

and want to form busses of the "columns" for lack of better terms. I can do it the long way:

```
   assign col31 = {row31[31], row30[31], ... row1[31], row0[31]} ;
```

but it's a lot of typing. Is there an easier way?

Comment: if you use vim/emacs, you may create a macro to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way within Verilog. Try creating a script to generate the code for you. You can have the code generated by your preferred programming language, then use an `` `include `` statement in your verilog file. Or you can go with an embedded route:

- Perl had EP3 : http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::EP3::Verilog
- Ruby has eRuby : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/eruby.htm
- Python has prepro : http://corner-case.com/indproj/prepro.html
- I'm sure something like it exists for other languages to. Such as Tcl, JavaScript, C, etc.

Concept is the same, just a difference in embedded language and tool used for conversion.

In this case, a double for-loop like the following will be needed:

```
foreach my $i (0..31) {
  foreach my $j (0..31) {
    printf("assign col%0d[%0d] = row%0d[%0d];\n", $i,$j, $j, $i);
  }
}
```

---

With *SystemVerilog* you could redefine your module with arrayed input/output ports. It may add difficulty when instantiating, and a synthesizer my attempt flatten the array. But it could work. Verilog does not support this, SystemVerilog does.

```
module row2col #(parameter WIDTH=32) (
    input wire [WIDTH-1:0] row [WIDTH],
    output logic [WIDTH-1:0] col [WIDTH]
  );
  always_comb begin
    foreach(row[i,j]) begin
      col[j][i] = row[i][j];
    end
  end
endmodule : row2col
```